# How to send multiple objects through HttpResponse or JsonResponse in django

Tags: django, django-views, httpresponse, jsonresponse

I have two objects influencer_data and user_list in my views function.I want to send both influencer_data and user_list through the HttpResponse method and obtain the data in Json format.

My views function is:

```
def index(request):
    influencers = Influencer.objects.all()

    influencer_data = serializers.serialize("json",influencers) 
    user_list = UserList.objects.all()
    user_list = serializers.serialize("json",user_list)
    context = {
        'influencer_data':influencer_data,
        'user_list':user_list,

    }


    return HttpResponse(influencer_data,user_list, content_type='application/json')
```

When I pass both influencer_data and user_list I get the error

```
__init__() got multiple values for argument 'content_type'
```

When I change the `return HttpResponse` statement to

```
return HttpResponse(context, content_type='application/json')
```

I get

```
influencer_datauser_list
```

i.e just the key values from the dictionary
When I change the `return` statement to

```
return HttpResponse(json.dumps(context), content_type='application/json')
```

I get the output as:

```
    "influencer_data": "[{\"model\": \"influencer_listings.influencer\", \"pk\": 8794, \"fields\": {\"full_name\": \"F A I Z S H A I K H \\ud83c\\udf08\", \"username\": \"mr_faizzz_07\", \"photo\": \"\", \"email_id\": \"\", \"external_url\": \"\", \"location_city\": \"Mumbai\", \"categories\": \"\", \"hashtags\": \"['#foryou', '#blessyou', '#all', '#faizanshaikh', '#keepsmiling', '#blessed', '#look',
```

(The Json object becomes a string)
When I pass only one object i.e either influencer_data or user_list. I get a Json object i.e it works correctly(I want data in the given format)

```
[
    {
        "model": "influencer_listings.influencer",
        "pk": 8794,
        "fields": {
            "full_name": "F A I Z S H A I K H ",
            "username": "mr_faizzz_07",
            "photo": "",
            "email_id": "",
            "external_url": "",
            "location_city": "Mumbai",
            "categories": "",
            "hashtags": "['#foryou', '#blessyou', '#all', '#faizanshaikh', '#keepsmiling', '#blessed', '#look', '#ramzan', '#loveyou', '#lover', '#cuteboys', '#keepgoing', '#picoftheday', '#feathers', '#brothers', '#faizshaikhhhh', '#pictures', '#jummahmubarak', '#lovers']",
```

How should I deal with this?

Comment: What you mean by *" just the key values from the dictionary"* ? Can you show the result? and in Which format you wish to get the data?

Comment: You can't represent ***two different kind of data(`Influencer` data and `UserList` data)*** as you desired unless you **do some magic**

Comment: Can I use REST api's to do this kind of thing?

Comment: What is the best thing you could do is the following setup, **`return HttpResponse(context, content_type='application/json')`**.

Comment: Actually I am making a web app whose front-end part is in react, so I need to pass the data in Json format.Also with each influencer_data I need to pass the user_list in which it can be added to.

Comment: Are you trying to do [DRF Nested Data Rep](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships) ?

Comment: Yes, I guess so, but I have never worked with DRF. How should I proceed?

Comment: docs..as we all do.

Comment: Can I do this without using the rest framework?

Answer (score 2):

```
def index(request):
    influencers = Influencer.objects.all().values()
    user_list = UserList.objects.all().values()
    context = {
        'influencer_data': influencer_data,
        'user_list': user_list,
    }
    data = json.dumps(context, indent=4, sort_keys=True, default=str)
    return HttpResponse(data, content_type='application/json')
```

Comment: When I use ```json.dumps``` it makes the json object a string.Something like this `"influencer_data": "[{\"model\": \"influencer_listings.influencer\", \"pk\": 8794, \"fields\": {\"full_name\": \"F A I Z S H A I K H \\ud83c\\udf08\", \"username\": \"mr_faizzz_07\", \"photo\": \"\", \"email_id\": \"\", \"external_url\": \"\", \"location_city\": \"Mumbai\", \"categories\": \"\",`

Comment: whats your end response,  in browser. And if you want object then remove default=str

Comment: hi Javed, did you try with mark_safe? from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe  and then mark_safe(json.dumps(...)). this has helped me to fix the string conversions